# Dynamically adding lots of Controls form another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface

I am learning multi threading in Win Forms using C# and according to sources the best way to achieve this is by invoking the main method from worker threads.

Now this all works good when heavy processing must be done and THEN the GUI is updated.

However I have a scenario where I need to programmatically add lots of controls inside a panel. This may go up to thousands (panel will be scrollable). Hence, since the controls are ultimately being added by the main thread, the program still hangs until this has been completed.

Is there any way around this? Or should I try and use some other control which doesn't require me to instantiate lots of controls simultaneously (as this is obviously a bit heavy).

Basically this panel contains a list together with an icon (depending on the state). Hence I am creating a label for every entry which I do not know if it the ideal way.

By the way I come from the web applications development department... Is there a control similar to a div in .NET? I looked at a rich text box but it doesn't seem to let you add an image in a straightforward way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I strongly suggest WPF instead of winforms for all .Net Windows application development. It is [Way Faster](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA) to handle large lists because it has built-in UI virtualization, hardware-acceleration, and vector-based graphics. winforms is a really old technology no one cares about anymore and is not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications.

Comment: BTW if you come from a web background the XAML + DataBinding approach will feel much more natural to you than the horrible procedural too-much-code-for-anything winforms approach. winforms doesn't support any types of customization and it performs really bad in scenarios where large amounts of UI elements are required.

Comment: And no, there's nothing like a `div` in winforms. winforms is really a wrapper around GDI+ which is a dinosaur piece of technology. It was not designed to be used for custom/modern/rich UI development, only for Windows 3.1-like stuff. You should really be using WPF.

Comment: Create an owner-drawn list and populate it dynamically as it scrolls. That limits the number of controls you create. The list is populated, but you control the drawing and render the controls as they're required.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a good reason to add hundreds of controls, let alone thousands.  It sounds like you need a custom control and you need to add items to it.

The ListBox or ListView control will work for a basic item but if you want lots of customizability you will have to reinvent the wheel yourself and draw everything manually.  It's a lot of work if you need to handle multiselect, scrolling, keyboard shortcuts, etc.

This is the strength of using WPF instead of Winforms since you can easily use the existing ListBox logic and have free range to customize the appearance of the items and even how they are arranged.

WPF has the concept of a virtualizing panel which can perform well even with thousands of items since it doesn't create the UI objects until an item is scrolled to.